# Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter- parent:

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, java-ee-6

someone help me out
I am getting this following issue while trying to save the pom.xml
file :

Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-
parent:pom:2.5.0 from http://uk.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be
reattempted until the update interval of UK has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.5.0 from/to UK (http://uk.maven.org/maven2): null to
http://uk.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.5.0/spring-boot-starter-
parent-2.5.0.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM

here's my pom.xml

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.5.0
 

com.example
MaBanque
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
MaBanque
Demo project for Spring Boot

<java.version>11</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-security


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf


org.thymeleaf.extras
thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Use https instead of http....

Answer (score 0):

was cached in the local repository,It looks like your maven can`t load
Try reinstall maven, and try generata this project using https://start.spring.io